# Encountering "Error 462: The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable" in VBA when an internet explorer automation script is running

Tags: excel, vba

I am running the below code to access a bank website and pull some data. This code runs on my computer, but it won't run on my bosses computer. I am encountering Error 462 at any point in the code when I try to set anything related to IE after the line containing `IE.Navigate URL1`.

Other posts mention this could be because Excel has created a reference for IE and I am encountering this error because that reference isn't being cleared, but I don't know exactly what that means. Again, only when running the code on a single computer in the office do I receive this error, but not when the code is run on the other three computers. We are both running 32-bit software, and have the same Excel versions.

He was running 64-bit software, and no one else in the office was. I thought that might be the issue, and uninstalled 64-bit Office and had the 32-bit suite installed on his computer. That didn't fix the issue. I thought there might be a problem with his Excel recognizing the reference library, Microsoft HTML Library needs to be active for the commands used to work, but his Excel shows those as active and running, too.

```
Public Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal HWND As Long) As Long

Option Explicit

Sub WaveRetrieveAccountHistory()
    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim Doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HWNDSrc As Long
    Dim URL1
    Dim URL2

    URL1 = "https://secure9.onlineaccess1.com/BroadwayBankOnline/Uux.aspx#/login"
    URL2 = "https://secure9.onlineaccess1.com/BroadwayBankOnline/Uux.aspx#/branches"

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate URL1

    Do While IE.Busy = True
        Loop

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

    HWNDSrc = IE.HWND
    SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc

    IE.Navigate URL2
End Sub
```

This is a snippet from a larger section of code that is going to be run at a scheduled time each day without a person present, which is why I have the line setting IE to the foreground (in case any other programs are open and taking priority).

Expected result is that the code would set the IE window to the foreground if it isn't already, and then navigate the second URL, but instead I am receiving Error 462 on the `HWNDSrc = IE.HWN"` line. When I remove those lines and run the code, it will also error out on `IE.Navigate URL2` with the same Error 462.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my issue ended up being to create a new user profile on Windows and completely deleting the old one. The original user profile had somehow become corrupted was our best guess, since uninstalling and reinstalling Excel didn't help, and this is also why the issue wasn't easy to replicate on other machines.